# Jenkins having problems when building github pull requests

Tags: scala, jenkins

I have Jenkins setup for a scala/sbt project on github. 
Everything seem to be working fine, except that the build being shown for Pull Request is done for the master branch (not for the branch which might be be merged). 
Anyone has faced this problem before? Any advice / suggestions?

PS. Unfortunately the repo is not public and I can't provide direct link. Although I can add logs and more details, if you think its gonna be useful.

Note: The PR I was referring to was the PRs from **forks**.

Comment: What branch set in jenkins as working branch?

Comment: The branch is set to `master`. But the question I was asking, was for PRs from **forks**.

Comment: There is a plugin/setting for building PRs in Jenkins.

Comment: I have it, and it runs, but as I mentioned, it only builds the master.